# Finding sum of sum(1)+sum(2)+....+(n)

Tags: c, math

I'm looking for solution to find the sum of numbers. Input will be given has n in integer and problem is to find Sum of the values of sum(1)+ sum(1+2) + sum(1+2+3) + ... + sum(1+2+..+n). I need a very optimised solution using dynamic programming or any math calculation.

```
int main()
{
    int sum = 0;
    int i = 0, n = 6;

    for( i = 1; i < n; i++ )
        sum = sum + findSumN( i );

    printf( "%d",sum );
}
```

Comment: The formula you give in the title, and the formula you give in your question, are different. Which is it?

Answer (score 4):

You can often find a formula for series like this by calculating the first few terms and using the results to search the [On-Line Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences](http://oeis.org/).

```
1 = 1
1 + (1+2) = 4
4 + (1+2+3) = 10
10 + (1+2+3+4) = 20
20 + (1+2+3+4+5) = 35
35 + (1+2+3+4+5+6) = 56
```

The sequence you're trying to calculate (1, 4, 10, 20, 35, 56, ...) is [A000292](http://oeis.org/A000292), which has the following formula:

```
a(n) = n × (n + 1) × (n + 2) / 6
```

Comment: Which is binom(n+2,3). The next stage of cumulative summation would give binom(n+3,4) etc.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the closed form of `sum(n)=1+2+…+n` and look up the Pascal's triangle identities. This gives immediately a very fast computation method.

As

```
binom(k,2) + binom(k,3) = binom(k+1,3) 
binom(k,2) = binom(k+1,3) - binom(k,3)
```

the summation of `binom(k+1,2)` from `k=M to N` results in the sum value

```
binom(N+2,3)-binom(M+1,3)=(N+2)*(N+1)*N/6-(M+1)*M*(M-1)/6 
  = (N+1-M) * ((N+1)²+(N+1)M+M²-1)/6
```

Answer (score 0):

If you play with the number you can find some patterns. Starts with

`sum(1 + 2 + 3 ... + N) = ((1 + N) * N) /2`

Then there is a relationship between the max number and the value above, that is from 1 the difference step 1/3 everytime the max number increase by 1. So get:

`(1 + ((1.0 / 3.0) * (max - 1)))`

I am not good enough at math to explain why this pattern occurs. Perhaps someone can explain it in a math way.

The following is my solution, no iteration needed.

```
int main()
{
    int min = 1;
    int max = 11254;
    double sum = ((min + max) * max / 2) * (1 + ((1.0 / 3.0) * (max - 1)));
    printf("%.f", sum);
}
```